# php html print file content - on docker

Tags: php, html, docker

I am using nginx docker image.

inside the container I have the following services.yaml file:

```
services:    
    - name: Aiden
      value: boy
    - name: Mia
      value: girl
```

I want to print out in a very simple way the content of services.yaml.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    $myfile = "/usr/share/nginx/html/values-versions.yaml";
    if(file_exists($myfile)){
        echo file_get_contents($myfile);
    } else {
        echo "FILE NOT EXIST!";
    }
?>
```

When I run this html I get a blank page, looks like the php doesn't work. Otherwise it would have printed "FILE NOT EXIST!".

Please suggest how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: You say you're using the nginx docker image, I assume the official one. More than likely that image does not include PHP. As such, PHP code is not being interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your code. You have missed semicolon. Please see updated code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    $myfile = "/usr/share/nginx/html/values-versions.yaml";
    if(file_exists($myfile)){
        echo file_get_contents($myfile);
    } else {
        echo "FILE NOT EXIST!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fixed it, but still getting same result.

Comment: There was another semicolon missing after echo "FILE NOT EXIST!". I have updated my code. Please check now.

Comment: When I run this code it worked for me https://prnt.sc/17ns90m There might some other issue either PHP not working or something.

Comment: I can see it prints out "FILE NOT EXIST!" but why it doesn't print it on the website itself?

Comment: There might some issue with php installed. Need to debug it. You can check issue by set error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Where should I pate error_reporting(-1); and where do I see the report?

Comment: You can write it on top of php file. Which will show error on browser itself.

Comment: Please see my edit. Is that what you suggest? Also, maybe I do not have php on this docker? Is there a way to install php \ check version ?